# Create a lot of files of specified size in Terminal (OSX)?

Tags: macos, file, command-line, terminal, file-manager

[I used this example to create one file:](http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/31/create-large-file-mac-os-x/)

```
mkfile -n size[b|k|m|g] filename

mkfile -n 1g ~/Desktop/LargeTestFile
```

But I need a lot of such files. How to create a lot of files using this command or clone multiple times this one file in Terminal in OSX? I need just any files of approximate specified size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example the following command creates 9 files of size 99 megabytes and names them `x001` - `x009`:

```
for i in {1..9};do mkfile -n 99m x$(printf '%03d' $i);done
```